# Excel - How to duplicate a specified column and its contents in a different sheet, using a cell as an input

Tags: excel, vba

How do I duplicate columns in sheet 2, Row G for example using input from cell in sheet 1 A4. The row and its contents should be copied by the number depicted in sheet 1 A4

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Thank you and noted. I have had a few poor attempts, nothing has got close as yet. I will copy in what I have tried shortly

Answer (score 0):

When you use the following line you are referring to the sheet "Sheet1" in the active workbook.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Make use of following commands in your VBA code to copy and paste data from cell of one worksheet to cell of another worksheet.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A4").Select
Selection.Copy

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("G4").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

For how to refer cells from two different worksheets/workbooks have a look at this post
[How to compare columns from two different excel workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107689/how-to-compare-columns-from-two-different-excel-workbooks)

Comment: Thanks Avidan. I have used those commands, but using a source cell for number of copies is where I fall on my face

Comment: You need to read this: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: Do you mean you need help in referencing adjacent cells?